# How to do a JDBC connection to redshift via sparkSession with a schema difference than public

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am trying to retrieve data from redshift in s spark program. The data is retrieved from an admin table (pg_table_def) so I cannot run unload command on it to s3. This means retriving it using JDBC, data is small so it is not a problem. I am trying to use sparkSession.read.jdbc which should work fine, the problem is that the table I am trying to query for is in a schema that is not public. Using regular sql commands I would run

```
set SEARCH_PATH to schemaName
```

However, read.jdbc returns a dataframe, and this command does not return data so I cannot use it. also writing schemaName.tableName in the SQL string, doesn't work.

Does anyone know of a way to change the schema on connection or any way to do a preSQL in read.jdbc? (I have seen some connection string for postgres that have &searchpath=schemaName, or @currenctSchema=schemaName, but so far none of them worked for me)

Thanks
Nir